# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Alright so this code was originally working but all of a sudden after tooling around with the code this error popped up:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId

It would just not go away even AFTER returning the code to its original state. I'm trying to make it so that if you click on the marker a InfoWindow would pop up which originally worked but now just gives me the error every time I click on a marker.

**Search Algorithm**

```
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        results.forEach((place) => {
          if (!place.name.includes("ديوان")) {
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map,
              position: place.geometry.location,
            });
  
      const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      MarkerPlaceID.set(marker, place.placeId);
      marker.addListener("click", () => {  
        handleMarkerClick(marker);
        resultRowCLick(marker);
      });
    
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
              infoWindows.forEach(function(infoWindow) {
                infoWindow.close();
              });
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            
            addNewResultRow(place.name, place.formatted_address, marker);
          } 
        });
  
        console.log("Nearby search results:", results);
      } else {
        console.error("Error performing nearby search:", status);
      }
    });
```

**handlerMarkerClick function**

```
function handleMarkerClick(marker) {
      infoWindows.forEach((infoWindow) => {
        infoWindow.close();
      });
     
    
      let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      
      window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
          infoWindow.close();
        }
      });

      const request = {
        placeId: marker.placeId,
        fields: [
          "name",
          "formatted_address",
          "photos",
          "formatted_phone_number",
          "website",
          "opening_hours",
          "rating",
          "reviews",
        ],
      };
    
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          let content = '<div style="max-width: 250px;">'; // Set max-width for the info window
    
          if (place.photos && place.photos.length > 0) {
            const photoUrl = place.photos[0].getUrl();
            content += '<div class="image-container">';
            content += `<img src="${photoUrl}" alt="${place.name}" style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 150px;">`;
            content += '</div>';
          }
          
          content += `<h2>${place.name}</h2>`;
          content += `<p>Address: ${place.formatted_address}</p>`;
    
         
          if (place.website) {
            content += `<p>Website: <a href="${place.website}" target="_blank">${place.website}</a></p>`;
          }
          if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
            content += `<p>Phone: ${place.formatted_phone_number}</p>`;
          }
          if (place.opening_hours) {
            content += `<div class="times">`
            content += `<br><p>Opening Hours:</p>`;
            content += `<p>${place.opening_hours.weekday_text.map(line => `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${line}`).join("<br>")}</p>`;
            content += `</div>`
          }
          if (place.rating) {
            content += '<div class="rating-container">';
  
            
            content += '<p>';
            content += `rating: &nbsp;${place.rating}`;
            for (let i = 0; i < place.rating; i++) {
              content += '&nbsp<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
            }
            
            content+= "</p>"
  
            content += '</div>';
          }
          if (place.reviews && place.reviews.length > 0) {
            content += '<p>Reviews:</p>';
            content += '<ul>';
            
            place.reviews.forEach((review) => {
              if (review.text && review.text.trim().length > 0) {
                content += `<li class="review-item">${review.text}</li>`;
              }
              else {

              }
            });
            
            content += '</ul>';
          }
    
          content += '</div>';
          infoWindow.setContent(content);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    
          infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
        } else {
          console.error("Error fetching Place Details:", status);
        }
      });
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out why the code does not work though I have found a few things:
`placeId` is undefined I printed it out. It was working before but now it just became undefined.

Comment: It seems like the `marker` parameter being passed in to `handleMarkerClick` does not have a `placeId` property.  Perhaps `MarkerPlaceID.set(…)` is not doing what you expect - it’s unclear to me what that does.

Comment: @James the thing is I am setting the marker id but the problem is not with ```MarkerPlaceID``` its with the ```place.placeId``` it self when I set the markers placeId to ```place.placeId``` it was undefined after debug I do not know how its possible for ```place.placeId``` to be undefined which is what made me take this different approach

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a StackSnippet in the question itself). What is `MarkerPlaceID`?

Comment: "I do not know how its possible for place.placeId to be undefined" it probably isn't undefined.  But marker.placeId is. You haven't shown any code where you are setting marker.placeId.

Comment: MarkerPlaceID is just a map in Java script, @James as for the the marker I have tried to console log both marker.placeId and place.placeId so they are both undefined

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript google maps api you do not get the placeId with

`place.placeId`

but with

`place.place_id`